# Dividing a string containing a letter and an int and defining them as new constants

Tags: java, string

i wanted to know if there is a simple way to convert a string, say "G20" into two seperate constants where letter= G and number = 20

E.G

```
input G20
letter=G;
number=20
```

Comment: You can use regex for pattern matching and find out if the character is string or an Integer.

Comment: if all three strings are constants, you can turn it around: `final String letter = "G";`, `final int number = 20;`, `final String input = letter + number;`,

Comment: Please note that your wording is somehow contradictory. Typically, a "constant" refers to a value which is known at compile time; and therefore you make a constant to something like `public final static int SOME_CONST  = 42` ... whereas you are also talking about user input (which obviously rules out to create a **constant**).

Comment: If I get you right, and you try to get a userinput once, parse this input into 2 variables and then never ever change them again, the most appropriate way might be using private variables for the parts. These parts would then have a public getter function and the object that contains the parts would have a constructor that allows to supply values for the parts.

Answer (score 0):

is the pattern constant in the input i.e; the string with contain char[] initially followed by numbers. If this is the case, we can use pattern matching to split the string.

Comment: The pattern will always be a single letter followed by any non negative number. Also if there is no number the number constant should be set to 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring` to get separate letter and number
[Refer this for understanding](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_substring_index.htm)

Answer (score 0):

if there is always one letter at the first character of string, you can get the first element as the letter and the remained as the number

letter=input[0];
number=input[1..sizeof(input)];

Answer (score 0):

I think that the most suitable solution is a regular expression.

In particular you can create two matching groups in order to capture the letter that comes before the numbers:

```
([A-Z])([0-9]+)
```

Using the [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) class you can get the two matching groups using the *group* method.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this :

public void splitString(String inputString){ //inputString = G20
   String strSubstring = inputString.charAt(0);
   int intSubstring = Integer.parseInt(inputString.substring(1,inputString.length());
}

Answer (score 0):

In case your 'G' can only be a single letter word following will work fine.

```
    String token = "G20";
    String letter = token.substring(0, 1);
    String number = token.substring(1, token.length());

    System.out.println("letter is : " + letter + "\nNumber is : " + number);//Prints out : letter is : G Number is : 20
```